# Defining synonyms for indexing

Tags: indexing, package-writing, documentation

Is it possible to set things up so that indexing synonyms does not generate multiple entries?  For example, if the text includes `\index{cur}`, `\index{hound}`, and `\index{mutt}`, can these be coalesced under the entry “dog”?  (Assume these keys are being automatically-generated; otherwise I’d just type `\index{dog}` every time.)

Background: LaTeX3/expl3 offers the possibility of defining certain variants of functions together.  In terms of the (experimental) class `l3doc`, an example might look like this:

```
% \begin{macro}[pTF]{\bool_if:N}
%   Blah blah blah.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \bool_if:N #1 { p , T , F , TF }
  { … }
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
```

In the documented code listings, this displays both `\bool_if:N(TF)` and `\bool_if_p:N` in the margins; in the generated code, this defines the four functions `\bool_if_p:N`, `\bool_if:NT`, `\bool_if:NF`, and `\bool_if:NTF`.

[Note: The notation `\bool_if:N(TF)` is the closest I can come on this site to showing the actual notation; but it’s close enough for this discussion.]

The trouble is that the automatic indexing of csnames from [`doc.sty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/doc) indexes this line as an instance of the non-existent function `\bool_if:N`!

[Note: `l3doc` adjusts catcodes so the colon & underscore are properly recognized.]

So…. Is there a way to tell the index-generation that the function variants are synonyms? *I.e.*, can the various places within the code where the variants are used be coalesced under one index entry?  (The entry would probably look something like `\bool_if:N(TF), \bool_if_p:N`.)

Alternate option: Is it possible to set things up so the single key `\bool_if:N` is recognized not as itself but as an instance of the four variants that actually exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need anything fancy in the `\index` argument (such as `@` or `!`), then this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \solomon_index:n \index

\NewDocumentCommand{\definesynonyms}{ m m }
 {
  \solomon_define_synonyms:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \solomon_define_synonyms:nn #1 #2
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \tl_gset:cn { g_solomon_syn_##1_tl } { #1 }
   }
 }

\RenewDocumentCommand{\index}{ m }
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { g_solomon_syn_#1_tl }
   {
    \solomon_index:v { g_solomon_syn_#1_tl }
   }
   {
    \solomon_index:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \solomon_index:n { v }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definesynonyms{dog}{cur,hound,mutt}

\begin{document}
\show\index
A\index{dog}
\newpage
B\index{cur}
\newpage
C\index{hound}
\newpage
D\index{mutt}
\newpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This is the contents of the generated `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{dog}{1}
\indexentry{dog}{2}
\indexentry{dog}{3}
\indexentry{dog}{4}
```

Comment: Cool! I’ll post a link to this on the LaTeX3 Issues list.